# Can Ruby record PCM microphone input in Linux ALSA system?

Tags: ruby, linux, pcm, alsa

Hi can ruby record microphone input in Linux ALSA system?

I would like to do some processing and encoding by ruby. But I couldn't find any related articles.

thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

A quick search turns up the [`ruby-alsa` project](http://projects.tryphon.eu/ruby-alsa):

```
# From the ruby-alsa homepage:
Capture.open do |capture|
  capture.read do |buffer, frame_count|
    $stdout.write buffer
  end               
end
```